# IOHIDManager.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, rfid

I am trying to compile this thing called SkyReader and when I do it gives me this:

```
gcc -c -o hid.o hid.c
hid.c:25:10: fatal error: IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h: No such file or directory
 #include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'hid.o' failed
make: *** [hid.o] Error 1
```

Do any of you people know a fix? I am still pretty new with make.

Comment: I believe `IOKit` is provided by OS X in the Xcode SDKs. You have to compile on MacOS. Also see [IOKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit) on the Apple Developer site.

Comment: I am trying to compile on linux EDIT: oh wait nvm https://github.com/silicontrip/SkyReader/issues/2